# how to use two mappers in VichUploader?

Tags: symfony, vichuploaderbundle

I tried to use two mappers in vich_uploader.yaml, but only the first one works, can u help me ?

here is the yaml file :

```
vich_uploader:
db_driver: orm

mappings:
   descripFileM:
      uri_prefix: /admin/descriptifs/M
      upload_destination: '%kernel.project_dir%/public/admin/descriptifs/M/'


   descripFileL:
      uri_prefix: /admin/descriptifs/L
      upload_destination: '%kernel.project_dir%/public/admin/descriptifs/L/'
```

The first mapping concerns:

```
/**
 * @ORM\Column(type="string", length=300, nullable=true)
 */
private $descriptif;

/**
 * @Vich\UploadableField(mapping="descripFileM", fileNameProperty="descriptif")
 * @var File|null
*/
private $descripFile;
```

The second concerns :

```
/**
 * @ORM\Column(type="string", length=300, nullable=true)
 */
private $descriptifL;

/**
 * @Vich1\UploadableField(mapping="descripFileL", fileNameProperty="descriptifL")
 * @var File|null
*/
private $descripFileL;
```

Comment: could you give us more information about the mapped proprities

Comment: it does not give any errors